# How to import global $woocommerce in Stripe's webhooks.php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, stripe-payments

I'm building Stripe based checkout and I want to create new order by using Woocommerce functions whenever 'payment_intent.succeeded' event happens. Problem is that `global $woocommerce` returns `null`. How do I import `global $woocommerce` successfully so that I can create orders programmatically?

I have tried importing wp-load.php file as mentioned in other threads with similar question, but that didn't seem to work.